# The Axis2 facets cannot be installed

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

I am trying to make axis2 webservice but I get following error

[image]

But I already have added the axis2 in the Windows > Prefrences > Web Services > Axis2 Preferences

[image]

Also I restart my eclipse but the problem remains same. I am using eclipse neon.

Answer (score 2):

This kind'a problems I correct it this way: the "Macho man way":

First of all, erase the axis2 from your eclipse, then:

1. Download the zip from the eclipse page
2. Unzip in somewhere well known to you
3. Go to the folder "dropins" in your eclipse folder
4. past there everything of the plugins folder from the unziped files
5. Don't forget reboot eclipse

For more details read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip) and this

- Choose the Axis2 war file's folder location in the Eclipse dialog at:

  Window -> Preferences -> Web Services -> Axis2 Emitter

Also see this answer:

[Axis error about runtime location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230168/axis-error-about-runtime-location)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145052/discussion-between-damian-lattenero-and-junaid).

Comment: Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230168/axis-error-about-runtime-location